# Running dockerized pgadmin as a service

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin

It works ok when running this way:

```
docker run -it --rm -p 5050:5050 --name testing fenglc/pgadmin4
```

But when I add it to a docker-compose then I'm unable to connect to localhost:5050. Same happens to thajeztah/pgadmin4 image

```
version: "3"
services:
  pgadmin:
    image: fenglc/pgadmin4
    ports:
      - "5050:5050"
```

Isn't it the same thing?

Comment: Yes the should map as it is. What is the error you get when trying to connect to `localhost:5050`? And errors in `docker-compose logs`?

Comment: I get no erros and I just noticed when I attatch to container then CTRL+P CTRL+Q doesn't work. But it works when using docker run.

Comment: Port is open but get no answer and browser is waiting

Answer (score 0):

Okie I missed the `-it` flag in your docker run statement. You need to have below compose

```
version: "3"
services:
  pgadmin:
    image: fenglc/pgadmin4
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "5050:5050"
```

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Linux Mint 18.1 Serena

Comment: Just found that it actually answers but content makes Chrome hanging. Running `curl -L localhost:5050` shows me a small difference between running directly and running in a service.

Comment: I ran it myself and it works fine in chrome using the same compose yaml?

Comment: I could access in Firefox but not in my Chrome. The order of css's are different in the HTML result line 5. Does it happen with you?
That is really weird to have different results.

Comment: Sometimes if a page has HTML errors then browser do their own corrections. Open the view source in firefox and see if you see and red colored tags showing errors

Comment: There is just one error but is the same in both tests. Going to network tab I see css order changing.
Anyway despite of Chrome bugs and pgadmin4 outputing different HTML I believe there is something changing in a lower layer that makes pgadmin4 to have a different behavior.

Comment: I really have my doubts on that. It should work the same way in both containers. The browsers may have difference

Comment: Not only browsers. We see differences in raw data with `curl`

Comment: It seems css order is random. Had same problem with an web app that returns a simple json. So it is a Chrome bug. Changing http://localhost to http://127.0.0.1 works